# How do I get the name of an object?

Tags: ruby

I have different objects, for example 
`Article` and `Medium`. When I use a helper, I would like to determine the name of the object (for example `Article`or `Medium`). How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-class

```
a = Article.new
a.class
# => Article
a.class.to_s
# => "Article"
```

also take a look at [is_a?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F) and [respond_to?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F). It's generally better to use [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) with `respond_to?` than the name of a class (generally).

Answer (score -2):

It is impossible. Constants and variables refer to the object. There is no way to get the name of it.

```
Article = Object.new
```

See that the value `Article` does not include information about its name:

```
Article
# => <#Object...>
```

Comment: Why do you assign an **instance** of `Object` to a constant? Didn't you mean something like `class Article < Object; end`

Comment: @GoshaArinich No I didn't mean that. I don't understand what you mean. Why would you make it a subclass instead of making it an object?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't assign an object to a constant. That's what made some confusion to me. If you mean an object, why don't you assign it to `article` rather than `Article`?

I also think @jakobk initially questioned how to get the name of the objects class, not the variable it was assigned to.

Comment: If you don't assign an object to a constant, so what? What relevance does that have to the question? It is not asking what **you** will do. The question states that there are objects `Article` and `Medium`, and the OP wants to get the name of them. What is wrong with assigning an object to a constant? If you never do so, why does Ruby have constants?

Comment: It's just a bad practice to assign objects to constants. Constants are meant for classes. Besides that, nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @GoshaArinich Constants are not meant to be used only for classes. You are totally wrong.

Comment: I think it's highly likely the OP is new to Ruby and the question was supposed to say "How do I get the type of an object" instead of the name, but if they've meant exactly what they've written then the answer given here is correct. There's nothing wrong with assigning instances to constants, it's just not the _usual_ convention, but the _main_ convention is to write code for humans, so as long as it's obvious I'd say it's ok.